# Proof of convexity for infinite dimensional optimal control problem

Tags: convex-optimization, optimal-control

Consider we have an infinite dimensional optimization problem. We have state variable $x\in R^N$ and input $u \in R^M$ and we have have following optimization problem.

J = $\int_{0}^{tf } L(x,u)dt$

subject to

$\dot{x} = f(x,u), ~~~g(x,u) \le 0$

I know for the standard optimization problem, we know that problem is convex if the objective function is convex and so are constraints. In the infinite dimensional problem, how we will proceed with the proof that problem is convex. Should I try to discretize the time and then proceed with the convexity definition.

Comment: The definition of convexity for a subset of a vector space is agnostic to whether the space is finite- or infinite-dimensional.  The same is true for the convexity of functions.  So, I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: My question is how to show that problem is convex when the objective function has integral sign and constraints are related via derivatives. Is my approach of discretisizing the problem and showing it for each time instant a valid approach.

Comment: You need some assumptions on the dynamics  and $g$ if the feasible set is to be convex.

Comment: What do you mean by assumptions on the dynamics? Is the continuity and ''well-defined'' valid assumptions for the dynamics and constraints?